# Creating a relationship to a relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to create a relationship to a relationship in Neo4j?

The use-case goes something like this:

- I have a bunch of questions, like "What movie should we see?"
- Each question can have many options like "Movie1", "Movie2", etc.
- For each question I want a user to be able to vote for their favorite option.

The graph would preferably look something like this:

```
(:Question {name:"What movie?"})-[:Option]->(:Movie {name:"Movie1"})
                                     ^   
                                     |
                                  [:Vote]
                                     |
                                  (:User)
```

I realize that one way I could solve this is with the following:

```
(:Question)-[:Option]->(:Movie)<-[:Vote]-(:User)
```

But then if I decide to remove the `Movie` as an `Option` in the future, I don't get to take advantage of `DETACH` and will have to manage removing the `Vote` relationship myself. Not to mention, if the `Movie` belongs to multiple categories, I have to keep track of which `Question->Movie` relationship it belongs to (probably with some sort of ID). It just seems very messy...

Is is possible to create a relationship to a relationship? Or am I going to have to manually enforce referential integrity?

Comment: Any chance you can edit the question to provide some real examples? I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the category/option/thing/vote schema.

Comment: Sure thing, can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is is possible to create a relationship to a relationship?

No. This is not possible. According [the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-relationships):

> **A relationship connects two nodes**, and is guaranteed to have a valid
>   source and target node.

That is: the start and end point of a relationship should be a node.

I believe you should do some changes in your data model. For example:

Maybe the `Option` can be a node and not a relationship. Make more sense, not? This way:

```
 (:Category)-[:HAS]->(:Option)
```

Also, the `Vote` can be a node too, and not a relationship... This way, when the user **makes** (a relationship, ahn?) a vote, this vote node will reference the option and the category that it is relative to.

```
 (:Category)-[:HAS]->(:Option)
          \           /
  [:FOR_CATEGORY][:FOR_OPTION]
            \      /
             (:Vote)
                |
            [:MAKES] 
                |
             (:User)
```

If, for example, you need to delete a `Option` and consequently the `:Vote`s related to it you can do something like:

```
MATCH (o:Option {id:10})<-[:FOR_OPTION]-(v:Vote)
DETACH DELETE o
DETACH DELETE v
```

Make any sense? Sorry for my ASCII art. :)

Comment: Makes sense— and the ASCII art is better than mine! :D

Comment: I was hoping I would be able to not have to manage referential integrity myself, because in your example I will still have to delete the Vote node if either Category or Option is removed. Correct? But at least it gets over the reference ID problem, which is a nice feature.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `DETACH DELETE` only removes relationships related to the node you are deleting... Note that the `:Vote` node is referencing both `:Category` and `:Option`. What is the expected behavior?  If I remove a `:Option` then I need to remove the `:Vote` and the relationship to `Category` too? Or the last can be maintained?

Comment: @JimHeising I updated my answer putting on it an example of query using `DETACH DELETE` to delete an `:Option` and the related `Votes`, including the Involved relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating this. The only reasonable way I can find is to assign an identifier to the relationship (`:HAS` in your case) and then use it in the pointing relationship (`:VOTE`).

Neo4j has internal IDs for this (see the `ID()` function), but I usually prefer to try to assign a semantically meaningful ID (like a person's national insurance number, a page URL or, in case of relations, the hash code of its concatenated endpoint's identifers).